# algorithm to identify book titles in tweets

Tags: algorithm, twitter, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I am trying to make a program that will analyse a large set of tweets and generate a report about the top 10 most popular books that people have tweeted about. The problem is I don't have any idea how to identify the book titles in tweets. It would be great if someone could name the algorithm for such type of work or at least guide me in the right direction.

Comment: There is no name of the one particular "algorithm" for what you're trying to achieve. it needs a mix of different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the list of book titles, [Wikipedia provides some lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_books). But if your goal is to compare new books (the best sellers of the summer) I guess they won't be in these lists. You can find other lists on Internet... Anyway (for reliability) you need a list.

Then, as @Adam_G told ealier:

> There is no way to automatically extract "book titles". For instance, how could you differentiate between someone talking about "the Martian" they saw in their backyard last night and the book by Andy Weir?

Let's imagine two books "The cat" and "The fear of green sharks".
There are many tweets containing the sequence "the cat" but in most cases these tweets are not about the book. Conversely, all the tweets containing "the fear of the green sharks" are about the book obviously.

So you should assign for each sequence of tokens a "probability" `P` to be the title of the book. In the previous example, "the cat" has a very low `P` and "the fear of the green sharks" a very high `P`. You can compute the value of `P` from the number of words in the title and the frequency of these words (and 2-gram, 3-gram,...) in the whole language (which can be computed using a big corpus)

Now consider this tweet:

> I read "The Cat" and I loved it!!

As human we understand that "The Cat" is a book because the tweet contains "read".
So, for titles with a low `P` (e.g. "the cat") you can try to use a machine learning algorithm to know whether the tweet is really about the book. The idea is to compute the probability for a tweet containing a title to really be about the book given the words in the tweet. Learn more about machine learning algorithms, for example Naive Bayes classifier.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a list of terms to search. Then just got through the tweets and check for instances of the book names in your list.

There is no way to automatically extract "book titles". For instance, how could you differentiate between someone talking about "the Martian" they saw in their backyard last night and the book by Andy Weir?